# Insertar un objeto en una lista enlazada simple

Tags: c++

Tengo que hacer un proyecto en c++, donde creo figuras (en un ambiente gráfico) y estas figuras se tienen que insertar en una lista enlazada.

A la hora de ver las coordenadas de las figuras que están insertadas en la lista, me muestra solo la coordenada de la última figura insertada no entiendo como corregir eso, ya tengo rato de buscar en ejemplos del curso y documentación de internet, no sé si se están insertando mal o es al hora de imprimir.

Este es el código donde creo la figura e inserto la figura a la lista:
.h

```
 class Circulo
    {
        private:
            int x,y,r1,r2;
            Figuras *fig=new Figuras();//reservo espacio de memoria para figura
            Lista_Figuras *ini=NULL;
        public:
            Circulo();
            ~Circulo();
            void crear(int,int,int,int,int);

    };

void Circulo::crear(int x,int y,int r1,int r2,int cls)
{
    setcolor(0);
    setfillstyle(1,cls);
    fillellipse(x,y,r1,r2);

    fig->setX(x);
    fig->setY(y);
    fig->setX1(r1);
    fig->setY1(r2);
    fig->setCls(cls);
    fig->setT(1);
    ini=ini->insertar(ini,fig);
    cout<<"Ini: "<<ini->getFigura()->getX()<<endl;
    ini->mostrarLista(ini);

}
```

Esta es la clase Figuras:

```
class Figuras
{
    private:
        int x,y,x1,y1,x2,y2,cls,t;
    public:
        Figuras();
        ~Figuras();
        void setX(int);
        void setY(int);
        void setX1(int);
        void setY1(int);
        void setX2(int);
        void setY2(int);
        void setCls(int);
        void setT(int);
        int getX();
        int gety();
        int getX1();
        int getY1();
        int getX2();
        int getY2();
        int getCls();
        int getT();

};

Figuras::Figuras()
{
    //ctor
    x=0;
    y=0;
    x1=0;
    y1=0;
    x2=0;
    y2=0;
    cls=0;
    t=0;
}

Figuras::~Figuras()
{
    //dtor
}
void Figuras::setX(int x)
{
    this->x=x;
}
void Figuras::setY(int y)
{
    this->y=y;
}
void Figuras::setX1(int x1)
{
    this->x1=x1;
}
void Figuras::setY1(int y1)
{
    this->y1=y1;
}
void Figuras::setX2(int x2)
{
    this->x2=x2;
}
void Figuras::setY2(int y2)
{
    this->y2=y2;
}
void Figuras::setCls(int cls)
{
    this->cls=cls;
}
void Figuras::setT(int t)
{
    this->t=t;
}
int Figuras::getX()
{
    return x;
}
int Figuras::gety()
{
    return y;
}
int Figuras::getX1()
{
    return x1;
}
int Figuras::getY1()
{
    return y1;
}
int Figuras::getX2()
{
    return x2;
}
int Figuras::getY2()
{
    return y2;
}
int Figuras::getCls()
{
    return cls;
}
int Figuras::getT()
{
    return t;
}
```

Esta es mi clase "Lista":

```
class Lista_Figuras
{
    private:
        Figuras *fig;
        Lista_Figuras *sig;
    public:
        Lista_Figuras();
        ~Lista_Figuras();
        void setFigura(Figuras*);
        void setSig(Lista_Figuras*);
        Figuras *getFigura();
        Lista_Figuras *getSig();
        Lista_Figuras *insertar(Lista_Figuras*,Figuras*);
        void mostrarLista(Lista_Figuras*);

};
 void Lista_Figuras::setFigura(Figuras *f)
{
    fig=f;
}
void Lista_Figuras::setSig(Lista_Figuras *s)
{
    sig=s;
}
Figuras *Lista_Figuras::getFigura()
{
    return fig;
}
Lista_Figuras *Lista_Figuras:: getSig()
{
    return sig;
}
Lista_Figuras *Lista_Figuras::insertar(Lista_Figuras *ini ,Figuras *fig)
{
    Lista_Figuras *N_Figura=new Lista_Figuras();
    Lista_Figuras *aux;
    N_Figura->setFigura(fig);
    if (ini==NULL)
    {
        ini=N_Figura;
        N_Figura->setSig(NULL);
        cout<<"Se inserto, estaba vacio\n"<<ini<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        aux=ini;
        N_Figura->setSig(aux);
        ini=N_Figura;

    }
    return ini;
}
void Lista_Figuras::mostrarLista(Lista_Figuras *ini)
{
    Lista_Figuras *aux=ini;
    Figuras *aux1;
    while(aux!=NULL)//recorre la lista asta que sea Null
    {
        aux1=aux->getFigura();
        cout<<aux->getFigura()->getX()<<" ";//muestra el numero actual de la lista conforme se valla moviendo
        if(aux->getSig()!=NULL)//si el siguiente es diferente de null dibueja un Flecha
        {
            cout<<"->";
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<endl;
        }
        aux=aux->getSig();//aunmenta de uno en uno la lista
    }
    if(ini==NULL){
        cout<<"Lista Basida"<<endl;
    }

}
```

En esta imagen se ve mejor el error:

[En la parte derecha es donde imprimo la lista, se ejecuta `ini->mostrarLista`(ini);](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyTUe.png)

Comment: Es muy difícil averiguar tu problema con la información que aportas. En `Circulo::crear` ¿Qué son `fig` e `ini`? usas esas variables pero su declaración no está en ningún lado.

Comment: Agregué lo que faltaba de código.

Comment: Intenta presentar un ejemplo mínimo que verifique el problema. No indicas cómo estás gestionando la lista de elementos (qué líneas usas para añadir elementos) ni tampoco cómo haces para imprimir la lista... lo más probable es que te estés quedando con el puntero equivocado

Comment: @jaroncascantePérez agregaste "*lo que faltaba de código*" pero no agregaste nada relevante, sigue sin saberse el origen de `fig` y sigue sin verse **cómo usas la clase `Lista_Figuras`**.

Comment: La línea se código que uso para insertar es {ini=ini->insertar(ini,fig);

Comment: @jaroncascantePérez ya vimos la línea en que llamas a `Lista_Figuras::insertar`. Lo que no vemos es ni dónde creas la instancia, ni dónde la usas. ¿no tienes un `main`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partiendo de la base de que el código que muestras es, tal y como te indican en los comentarios, incompleto, yo veo dos problemas básicos:

**Problema 1**

`Lista_Figuras` pretende ser una lista y un nodo de la lista a la vez. Esto crea una interfaz oscura y compleja... ¿de verdad para añadir un nodo a la lista es necesario hacer esto?

```
ini=ini->insertar(ini,fig);
```

Donde `ini` aparece nada más y nada menos que tres veces ¿¿?? El homólogo en la STL sería que, para añadir un elemento a un vector tuvieses que hacer algo así:

```
std::vector<int> datos;
datos = datos.push_back(datos,1);
```

En una lista bien construida, la línea que te he comentado debería parecerse más bien a esto:

```
ini->insertar(fig);
```

En esta nueva línea cualquiera con un mínimo de experiencia programando entiende que `ini` es alguna especie de contenedor en el cual se añade un elemento, `fig`.

Otro ejemplo de lo complejo de la interfaz lo encontramos en la propia implementación de `insertar`:

```
if (ini==NULL)
{
  ini=N_Figura; // <<--- AQUI!!!
  N_Figura->setSig(NULL);
  cout<<"Se inserto, estaba vacio\n"<<ini<<endl;
}
else
{
  aux=ini;
  N_Figura->setSig(aux);
  ini=N_Figura; // <<--- AQUI!!!
}
```

El problema aquí es que `ini` es una variable **local**, luego las líneas comentadas son cambios locales. El puntero original no se entera de este cambio. Es tentador pensar, al pasarle un puntero a una función, que el puntero va a actualizarse con la nueva información y en este caso no es así, luego si a alguien le da por hacer esto:

```
ini->insertar(ini,fig);
```

va a tener un problema dificil de encontrar. Además de que permite otros usos cuanto menos dignos de un libro de artes oscuras. ¿Cómo quedaría el programa después de una instrucción así?

```
ini = ini->insertar(otra_lista,fig);
```

La solución a este problema de diseño pasa por dividir `Lista_Figuras` en dos objetos (suponiendo que sea necesario): contenedor y nodo. El contenedor se limita a gestionar la lista de nodos y cada nodo... pues eso, es un nodo y almacena información sobre sí mismo únicamente... lo mismo hasta descubres que no hace falta la clase *nodo*.

**Problema 2**

Vamos a repasar detenidamente el siguiente código:

```
class Circulo
{
private:
  int x,y,r1,r2;
  Figuras *fig=new Figuras();//reservo espacio de memoria para figura
  Lista_Figuras *ini=NULL;
public:
  Circulo();
  ~Circulo();
  void crear(int,int,int,int,int);
};

void Circulo::crear(int x,int y,int r1,int r2,int cls)
{
  setcolor(0);
  setfillstyle(1,cls);
  fillellipse(x,y,r1,r2);

  fig->setX(x);
  fig->setY(y);
  fig->setX1(r1);
  fig->setY1(r2);
  fig->setCls(cls);
  fig->setT(1);
  ini=ini->insertar(ini,fig);
  cout<<"Ini: "<<ini->getFigura()->getX()<<endl;
  ini->mostrarLista(ini);
}
```

A falta de indicar el código del constructor... ¿No ves nada raro o peligroso? Vuelve a leerlo y presta atención a la variable `ini`. ¿Ves algo ahora? Yo me he encontrado con esto (eliminando el ruido):

```
class Circulo
{
private:
  Lista_Figuras *ini=NULL;
public:
  void crear(int,int,int,int,int);
};

void Circulo::crear(int x,int y,int r1,int r2,int cls)
{
  ini=ini->insertar(ini,fig);
}
```

Es decir, `ini` empieza a puntando a `NULL`, luego no hay memoria reservada para la lista... y sin embargo se llama a `ini->insertar` alegremente... ¿Seguro que la aplicación no falla? Mucho ojo con el uso de punteros. Está genial que los inicialices... pero antes de usarlos hay que estar muy seguro de que apuntan a un objeto o reserva de memoria válidos.

Este problema se solucionaría solo al aplicar una solución al *problema 1*, ya que al dividir `Lista_Figuras` lo normal es que te des cuenta de que o bien no hace falta tener un puntero que gestione la lista de figuras o bien, como solo va a haber una única lista, el objeto se puede inicializar en el constructor sin problemas.

Esto no tiene por qué solucionarte el problema, pero tu pregunta aun deja mucho que desear y te noto bastante atascado. Lo ideal es que reconstruyas la pregunta y presentes un ejemplo mínimo y completo que reproduzca el problema. Y con completo me refiero a eso, completo, un código que pueda copiar en mi equipo y verificar tu problema sin tener que inventarme líneas de código.

Comment: Gracias por la contribución, resolví el "problema antes, y con lo que acabas de redactar me va a funcionar para futuros proyectos de la U, apenas estoy empezando a entender listas, y por eso cometo errores bastantes ingenuos  .